# .htaccess RewriteBase vs html Base?

Tags: html, .htaccess

I have a folder inside the root called `someAppName` and users can logout by going to the link `someAppName/logout`. Users need to be able to logout from anywhere in the site. For instance when they are editing their list of regrets. But when users go to `/someAppName/regret-list/edit/<someRegretID>` and are done editing it takes them to `/someAppName/regret-list/edit/logout` which is not an existing route.

I thought I fixed this already by adding a `.htaccess` file and using `RewriteBase` to `/someAppName/` and instead directing users to `/logout` but instead of reaching `/someAppName/` they are not arriving at `/logout` which is not the intended behavior.

I am pretty sure I can fix this by using the `html Base` property but I don't understand why my `.htaccess` file does not help? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I find that `.htaccess: RewriteBase` works to rewrite the base of your rewrites. This means that routing does not work correctly without it when you move your application out of the root folder and it is needed for that.
It appears that I also need `html Base` in order to get links absolute going to the right places.

tl;dr

You probably need both, one for Apache mod rewrite and the other for common absolute links. That is unless you wish to include the new parent directory path in every link.